# C function pointer in a struct not changing the values when called

Tags: c, struct

I have a node struct that has a function which will increment it's valuestruct

```
node {
  int value;
  struct node * left;
  struct node * right;
  void (*incrementValue)(struct node);
};

void incrementNodeValue(struct node this){
  this.value ++;
  printf("the value is now %d\n", this.value);
}

int main(){
  struct node firstLeft = { 5, NULL, NULL, incrementNodeValue };
  struct node firstRight = { 15, NULL, NULL, incrementNodeValue };
  struct node start = { 10, &firstLeft, &firstRight, incrementNodeValue };
  start.incrementValue(start);
  printf("%d\n", start.value);
  return 0;
}
```

My intention is that start.incrementValue will increase the value from 10 to 11.
When I compile and run this code (with no warnings), it prints

> the value is now 11
>
> 10

So I know that the value is changed in the function, but once it exits the function seems no to have had any effect.

Comment: I tried doing exactly what you said, but it gave the error: `error: ',' expected (got "&")`

Comment: Yeah, I think I mixed my c++ and c syntax, sorry about that.

Comment: don't use `this` as a variable name. Everyone will think you're coding c++...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void incrementNodeValue(struct node this)` declares a function that receives the **value** of a `struct node`. The value is only a copy of the contents. So the function only changes a copy; it does not change the original `start` object in the main routine.

To change the original object in the function, change the declaration so the function receives the address of a `struct node`:

```
void incrementNodeValue(struct node *this)
```

Then change the call so it passes the address:

```
start.incrementValue(&start);
```

Inside the function, you have to change the code to use `this` as a pointer rather than as a `struct`, so `this.value` becomes `this->value`.

And you will need to change the declaration inside the `struct node` to:

```
void (*incrementValue)(struct node *);
```

Comment: this is correct. I am new to stack overflow so it won't let me accept your answer for another 6 minutes,  but this did work.